# How to use a histogram to get the white pixel intensity?

Tags: c#, image-processing, histogram, aforge

[image]I am developing a number plate recognition system and I have managed to locate the number plate area successfully. But I need to filter out the false number plate areas from the image. I am thinking is to use a histogram and probably check the horizontal pixel intensity.

would this be a correct approach? or are there any better approach?

Comment: You may need to be more specific because number plates in different countries (or states, or counties) can look different. As well as government issue plates, fleet plates, front vs rear plates, personalized plates and the year of the plate can all have different color schemes. Is white the lettering or the background, what's the contrasting color?

Comment: @joccer I am targeting the UK number plates with white lettering and black background.

Comment: Might be helpful if you put an image of a UK plate up here so we can see what you are referencing!

Comment: @trumpetlicks ive attached the image! thanks

Comment: OK, so what do you mean by the "false number plate area"?

Comment: @trumpetlicks well when you are trying to locate number plate areas I need to filter out the unwanted rectangular areas that may contain in the image which are non-number plate areas.

Comment: I have to admit, I wouldn't do this with a color based histogram filter.  I would look into edge detecting, and look for a "rectangularish" area with the approximate dimensions you are looking for.  the delete everything else outside of the plate!

Comment: so thats what I am doing. the issue I have is how to remove the other areas except the number plate? also using exact dimensions will be an issue if the distance from the camera to the vehicle changes

Comment: Then look for proportion instead of exact dimensions!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plate is an aerea of high contrast, you should take advantage of that. Also there are a lot of edges, and especially 90 degrees edges.

Comment: yeah you are right! Can I use something like a histogram to get the maximum vertical edge intensity? Does it make sense? or is it even possible? I'm sorry I'm quite blunt on this

Comment: edge detection is a matter no-one could explain in a few words, i'm afraid. Contrast is more simple, first have a try with your bank of test input image to see how well it works with contrast.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example using EmguCV in C#, maybe you can find something useful, it is example of recognizing a stop sign: [Stop sign detection](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Traffic_Sign_Detection_in_CSharp)